# PHP, how post/get hidden value (id) from dropdown meniu?

Tags: php

how post/get hidden value (id) from dynamic drop-down menu?

```
<select name="motinine">
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id, Name FROM mothebord ORDER BY name");
 <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $pav =$row['Name'];
      echo "<option>$pav</option>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Dynamic drop-downs have no hidden value.

Comment: @phpNoOb: he's probably looking for `<option value="some_id">name</option>` , the `value="some_id"` part.

Comment: No argument about that...

Comment: Thnx DCoder, i solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the id in the value attribute of the options.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$pav.'</option>';
```

Give the select a name.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <select name="motherboard">
        <option value="1">Name1</option>
        <option value="2">Name2</option>
        <option value="3">Name3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And retrieve it in your php file using `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the `method`, or simply `$_REQUEST`.

```
$_POST["motherboard"] // contains the selected value
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your option a value

`echo "<option value='$pav'>$pav</option>";`

Then you can retrieve the data with

`$_POST['motinine']` if using POST

`$_GET['motinine']` if using GET

or

`$_REQUEST['motinine']` with either one.